Sampling from Gaussian distribution with linear constraints
I have tried to sample from a Gaussian distribution with linear constraints.
More precisely, I want to sample $x_i$ ($i=0,\cdots,n$) from the Gaussian which satisfies $x_{i+1}-x_i<const$. With rejecting style, it takes a long time to sample when $n$ gets large enough.
Does anybody know clever solutions for this?
Thanks in advance!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I think what you are asking for will give you random variables which are not really gaussian anymore. Imposing this restriction imposes a strong non-linear dependence on the random variables. You may look up the multivariate truncated normal distribution, I think this might be helpful.
